# Indexerror: list index out of range for excel file

Tags: python, excel, glob

I have this piece of code i am trying to run :

```
import glob
filenames=list(glob.glob("../Data/atp_data.csv"))
l = [pd.read_excel(filename,encoding='latin-1') for filename in filenames]
no_b365=[i for i,d in enumerate(l) if "B365W" not in l[i].columns]
no_pi=[i for i,d in enumerate(l) if "PSW" not in l[i].columns]
for i in no_pi:
    l[i]["PSW"]=np.nan
    l[i]["PSL"]=np.nan
for i in no_b365:
    l[i]["B365W"]=np.nan
    l[i]["B365L"]=np.nan
l=[d[list(d.columns)[:13]+["Wsets","Lsets","Comment"]+["PSW","PSL","B365W","B365L"]] for d in [l[0]]+l[2:]]
data=pd.concat(l,0)
```

Everytime i do however, i am getting this error:

```
indexerror: list index out of range
```

Here are the list of columns in the mentioned `atp_data.csv` file:

```
['ATP', 'Location', 'Tournament', 'Date', 'Series', 'Court', 'Surface', 'Round', 'Best of', 'Winner', 'Loser', 'WRank', 'LRank', 'WPts', 'LPts', 'W1', 'L1', 'W2', 'L2', 'W3', 'L3', 'W4', 'L4', 'W5', 'L5', 'Wsets', 'Lsets', 'Comment', 'B365W', 'B365L', 'CBW', 'CBL', 'EXW', 'EXL', 'IWW', 'IWL', 'PSW', 'PSL', 'MaxW', 'MaxL', 'AvgW', 'AvgL']
```

Anyone know the soultion to this?

Answer (score 0):

nvm, I found the error. I was using `read_excel` instead of `read_csv` to read a csv file.